# How to load single DLL in multiple process in vc++

Tags: c++, dll

I have created a dll in c++ which is loaded in all active processes.I want to know is there any way by which this dll load only one time and that single copy will be shared by all processes.

```
CPhoneticProcessor * g_pPhoneticProcessor = NULL;
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                  DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                  LPVOID lpReserved
                  )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        g_pProcessor = new CPProcessor();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        if(g_pProcessor)
            delete g_pProcessor;
        g_pProcessor = NULL;
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Every Process When loads dll it create new instance of class CPProcessor so i want only one instance to be shared between all the processes.
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "instance"?

Comment: I want one copy of object of class CPProcessor i.e g_pProcessor to be shared between all the process in which dll is loaded

Comment: You need to implement some IPC. Please don't ask the question in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data_seg feaure.Plese check following link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Is it possible to share object using data_seg feature.Because I want to share object.

Comment: No, you can't share the object.